# Задача, условный оператор

Tags: python, if

(может быть, не совсем по назначению использую сайт)

Задача:

Работа светофора для пешеходов запрограммирована следующим образом: в
начале каждого часа в течение трех минут горит зеленый сигнал, затем в течение
двух минут — красный, в течение трех минут — опять зеленый и т. д.
Дано вещественное число t, означающее время в минутах, прошедшее с начала
очередного часа. Определить, сигнал какого цвета горит для пешеходов в
этот момент.

Я предлагаю такой код, но можно ли его как-нибудь оптимизировать, сделать проще?

```
    Time_Left = int(input('enter time  in minutes since begining of hour'))

'''Узнаем число уже прошедших циклов "зеленый-красный" и берем ЦЕЛУЮ часть от деления'''
x = Time_Left // 5

'''Находим разницу между Time_Left и числом полных пройденных циклов, 
   умноженных на время одного цикла "зеленый-красный"'''
l = Time_Left - (x * 5)

if l == 0:
    print('it is red')
elif l == 1:
    print('it is green')
elif l == 2:
    print('it is green')
elif l == 3:
    print('it is green')
elif l == 4:
    print('it is red')
elif l == 5:
    print('it is red')
```

Поясню почему так сделал:

Построим таблицу зависимости цвета от времени:

g - зеленый

r - красный

```
 1. -- g
 2. -- g
 3. -- g
 4. -- r
 5. -- r
 6. -- g
 7. -- g
 8. ...
```

5 минут - это полный цикл, и мы знаем какой минуте соответствует какой сигнал. Соответственно, если мы узнаем разницу между настоящим моментом времени и целым количеством пройденных циклов и основываясь на том, что:

```
 1. -- g
 2. -- g
 3. -- g
 4. -- r
 5. -- r
```

Мы можем сделать вывод о том, какой цвет сейчас горит.

Comment: Нужно взять остаток от целочисленного деления на 5 вещественного числа t, далее если остаток <= 3 значит зеленый, иначе красный.

Comment: То что написал @Bulson выглядит так: `"g" if Time_Left%5 <= 3 else "r"`

Answer (score -1):

```
print('green' if 0 <= float(input()) % 5 <= 3 else 'red')
```

Comment: elif не нужно, в этом случае достаточно и else.